# Make WCF 4 WSDL look like Web Service WSDL?

Tags: wcf, web-services, priority-queue

I have an ancient web service client that needs to talk to my WCF 4.0 service. The client is a large old system in a another company that is not going to change. We have new clients that needs WCF functionality, so we have it, but now some more work is needed to support the old client.

I have decorated several parts of the WCF service with Attributes, and a lot of the emitted WSDL looks like the web service that the ancient client used to call. I have a few more parts that don't look like the legacy stuff. Where can I look to make the new server look like the old?

The old (Web Service) system has:

```
<wsdl:portType name="QueueServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="SubmitRequest">
<wsdl:input message="tns:SubmitRequestSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:SubmitRequestSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

The new (WCF Service) system has:

```
<wsdl:portType name="QueueServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="SubmitRequest">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="https://test.com/SubmitRequest" message="tns:QueueServiceSoap_SubmitRequest_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="https://test.com/QueueServiceSoap/SubmitRequestResponse" message="tns:QueueServiceSoap_SubmitRequest_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

I need to change the WCF service to look like the WS one... Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Publish your service binding here please.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the WSDL? Does the old client need to read it? Is it causing a problem? Are the message formats different? You haven't really said what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `HttpModule` that handles `BeginRequest`, using that to attach a Response Filter when WSDL is asked for `(Request["WSDL"] != null)`.  The response filter will be a class you write that inherits from `MemoryStream`, that will alter the response appropriately.

Add good reference for writing the Response Filter can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

Comment: this will work for a "?WSDL" request, but not for a metadata exchange request. Also, what if his new service actually _does_ match his new WSDL? He'd better get the _service_ to match the old WSDL before he worries about getting the _WSDL_ to match the old WSDL.